# PHP returning wrong date on windwos 7

Tags: php, datetime

I am using windows 7, with `wamp` for development;
My pc current time is set to 24 hours format and my current time is 12:03

the following `php` code returning `2014-04-07 07:03`

Code:

```
$current_time = date("Y-m-d H:i", time());
die($current_time);
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Create empty file and write `<? phpinfo(); ?>` in it. When you open that file in browser, there will be timezone written somewhere in it. Check if it matches. If you need to change it, you can do so in `php.ini`.

Comment: yes, Default timezone : UTC

Comment: Yeah, adjust it as you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP default timezone `UTC` so time will be shown according timezone, you can also change timezone by following function [**date_default_timezone_set**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London') // or add your local timezone 
$current_time = date("Y-m-d H:i", time());
die($current_time);
```

Comment: I am on GMT+5 how can I add this time. As I don't know the 'Erope/London' like string of my timezon?

Comment: @Sarah, If you want to your local time display by `PHP` date function then set your local timezone string in `date_default_timezone_set` function, **timezones list** http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php